# Local expression of differential forms of a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles

Let $ p: M \to B $ be a smooth vector  bundle over B.

I'm wondering how to express  a differential form on M  in local coordinates. I'm aware of the local expression of a differential form on a arbitrary smooth manifold, but I'm not sure if in the case of vector bundle over B there will be something special in the local expression of a differential form by using the base space B for example .

Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing different about this setting. You can locally use product coordinates on $B\times\Bbb R^k$. There is also a notion of differential forms *with values in* a vector bundle, but I don't think you're there yet. By the way, you have a typo: $p$ gives a vector bundle over $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment, I will write my comment as an answer.

Vector bundle also has a smooth manifold structure where the local trivialisation defines a smooth structure. Now try to write 1-form in terms of local coordinates.

For example, Suppose $(U,(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n))$ be a smooth chart containing $p \in M$. Then $\{dx_i, 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ denotes the dual basis of cotangent spaces ${T^*}_p M$. Since 1- form is a covector field ( i.e. it assigns a covector at each point $p \in M$), so we can express our 1-form $\alpha = \Sigma_{i=1}^{i=n} a_i(p) dx_i|_p $ for each $p \in U$.